# Can I change my kernel security level?

Tags: security, administrator, kernel

When I run `sysctl kern.securelevel` on my Mac, it gives me a value of 0.

I'd like to increase the kernel security level on my computer. I want it to give me a 1.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in a [related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/177193/18101).

**Change it temporarily until next reboot**

`sudo sysctl kern.securelevel=1`

**Change it for future startup**

`sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf`

Once in vi editor, press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter insert mode, then type `kern.securelevel=1`. Next press <kbd>enter</kbd>, then <kbd>:</kbd>, then type `wq` and press <kbd>enter</kbd> one last time.

Comment: Sweet, can you help me understand what this changes?

Comment: I'm concerned that the work-around is to delete the line in `sysctl.conf`. Can I lock the file?

Comment: @Cauder Those sound like different questions. If you don't understand the effects of changing your security level, why did you ask *how* to do it? Consider asking a new question that goes right to the root of what you're trying to accomplish.